# Calculating field to equal adjacent polygon field when field = 0

Tags: polygon, field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I have a polygon Feature Class in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0

In the image below, yellow is when the field value is 0, and blue is all other values.

I want to calculate all the 0 values to equal the adjacent polygon value of the same field.

[image]

Comment: I would start by identifying neighbors to each polygon using the Polygon Neighbors tool.

Comment: Have you tried [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm)?. But that will alter the geometries.